# How to evaluate $\left(\cos{\frac{5\pi}{9}}\right)^{11}+\left(\cos{\frac{7\pi}{9}}\right)^{11}+\left(\cos{\frac{11\pi}{9}}\right)^{11}$

Tags: trigonometry

How to evaluate $$\left(\cos{\frac{5\pi}{9}}\right)^{11}+\left(\cos{\frac{7\pi}{9}}\right)^{11}+\left(\cos{\frac{11\pi}{9}}\right)^{11}?$$

I found the problem on this [page](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1590435487894164&set=gm.1552930164974078&type=1&theater&__mref=message).

Comment: Say your each term(without the exponent) is $x,y,z$. Then $x,y,z$ are the three solutions of $\cos\alpha$ in $$1/2=\cos3\alpha=4\cos^3\alpha-3\cos\alpha$$

Comment: My hunch is that the fact $\cos 5\pi/3=\cos7\pi/3=\cos11\pi/3=1/2$ comes to the fore. Remember that $\cos3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$. This means that all those cosines are solutions of the equation
$$4x^3-3x=\frac12.$$

Comment: The expression in question is the negative real root of the polynomial equation $$441526941+2804041728~x-11626610688~x^2+8589934592~x^3=0,$$ where the LHS is irreducible over $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Comment: But are you sure about the last angle? IMHO it should be $\cos17\pi/9$? Then all the solutions of that equation are used equally. Now two of those cosines are equal.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's true...

Comment: If @JyrkiLahtonen's suggestion is correct, then the result is $\dfrac{231}{2^9}$

Comment: @Lucian: Well done! You beat me to it by one minute :-)

Comment: An evaluation: $-0.1066163094863520159486374601299698275634$.

Comment: @Lucian, As $\dfrac{7\pi}9+\dfrac{11\pi}9=2\pi;\cos\dfrac{7\pi}9=\cos\dfrac{11\pi}9$  and $4x^3-3x=\dfrac12$ does not have a repeated root. $\cos3A=\dfrac12=\cos\dfrac\pi3\implies A=\dfrac{(6m+1)\pi}9$ where $m\equiv-1,0,1\pmod3$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Frieder's final expression, there is a terrible closed form since $$\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{1-i \sqrt{3}}+\sqrt[3]{1+i \sqrt{3}}}{2 \sqrt[3]{2}}$$ $$\cos \left(\frac{2\pi }{9}\right)=2\cos^2 \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)-1$$ $$\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{9}\right)}{2}}$$ After Lucian's comment, this is $$\frac{231}{512}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right)
   \sqrt[3]{A}}{4096}-\frac{132463\ 3^{2/3} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right)}{2048\ 2^{2/3}
   \sqrt[3]{A}}$$ with $A=-42951219+93177701 i \sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using for an odd $n$
$${\cos ^n}(x) = \frac{1}{{{2^{n - 1}}}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\frac{{n - 1}}{2}} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \cos ((n - 2k)x)$$
gives me:
$${\cos ^{11}}(t) = \frac{{462\cos (t) + 330\cos (3t) + 165\cos (5t) + 55\cos (7t) + 11\cos (9t) + \cos (11t)}}{{1024}}$$
It follows therfore:
$${\cos ^{11}}\left( {\frac{{5\pi }}{9}} \right) = \frac{{154 - 462\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{{18}}} \right) + 56\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{9}} \right) - 165\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{9}} \right)}}{{1024}}$$
$${\cos ^{11}}\left( {\frac{{7\pi }}{9}} \right) = \frac{{154 - 56\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{{18}}} \right) + 165\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{9}} \right) - 462\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{9}} \right)}}{{1024}}$$
and
$${\cos ^{11}}\left( {\frac{{11\pi }}{9}} \right) = \frac{{154 - 56\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{{18}}} \right) + 165\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{9}} \right) - 462\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{9}} \right)}}{{1024}}$$
summing up:
$${\cos ^{11}}\left( {\frac{{5\pi }}{9}} \right) + {\cos ^{11}}\left( {\frac{{7\pi }}{9}} \right) + {\cos ^{11}}\left( {\frac{{11\pi }}{9}} \right) = \frac{{462 - 574\sin \left( {\frac{\pi }{{18}}} \right) + 386\cos \left( {\frac{\pi }{9}} \right) - 1089\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{9}} \right)}}{{1024}}$$
$$ \approx  - 0.10661630948635201594863746012996982756343832484191$$